@RestClientTest without mocking Azure OAuth
Having some issues correctly setting up @RestClientTest that is using a RestClient with the new OAuth Interceptor that will be available in Spring Boot 3.4. The particular RestClient requires the OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager bean which I assume is not being injected when running the @RestClientTest test slice. Any suggestions on a solution I can use because I'd like to avoid spinning up the entire Spring Boot context (i.e., use @SpringBootTest).
This is my RestClientConfig
@Bean
    public RestClient restClient(
            RestClient.Builder builder, OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        var client = builder.baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .requestInterceptor(new OAuth2ClientHttpRequestInterceptor(authorizedClientManager))
                .defaultRequest(request -> request.attributes(clientRegistrationId(CLIENT_REGISTRATION_ID)))
                .build();

        return HttpServiceProxyFactory.builderFor(RestClientAdapter.create(client))
                .build()
                .createClient(RestClient.class);
    }


My test class
@RestClientTest(RestClient.class)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0})
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@Import(RestClientConfig.class)
@AutoConfigureMockRestServiceServer(enabled = false)
class RestClientTest {

    @Autowired
    RestClient RestClient;

    @Test
    void test1() {
       
    }
}



As expected, the error I'm getting,
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'restClient' parameter 1: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager'

[UPDATE]
After looking at the link provided by @jcompetence I added a test configuration that loads all the required beans.
@TestConfiguration
public static class TestConfig {

    @Value("${wiremock.server.port}")
    private int port;

    @Bean
    ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        var client = new AuthorizationClientProperties();
        client.setAuthorizationGrantType(CLIENT_CREDENTIALS);
        client.setScopes(List.of("application-id-test.default"));

        var aadProperties = new AadAuthenticationProperties();
        aadProperties.getAuthorizationClients().put("client-registration-id", client);
        aadProperties.getCredential().setClientId("application-id-test");
        aadProperties.getCredential().setClientSecret("client-secret-test");
        aadProperties.getProfile().getEnvironment().setActiveDirectoryEndpoint("http://localhost:" + port + "/microsoft");
        aadProperties.getProfile().setTenantId("tenant-test-id");
        return new AadClientRegistrationRepository(aadProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientService auth2AuthorizedClientService(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oAuth2AuthorizedClientService) {
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build();
        var auth2AuthorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, oAuth2AuthorizedClientService);
        auth2AuthorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        return auth2AuthorizedClientManager;
    }
}


How would you like for SpringBoot to inject this bean if the SpringBoot Context does not get initialised?  Look into TestConfiguration.  You can mock the OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager or @Mock.  Honestly not sure how else you would do this...

I was hoping for some customised TestConfiguration to be implemented, which injects the required bean, or some AutoConfiguration annotation like RestClientAutoConfiguration or AadAutoConfiguration that might be available for this type of scenario.

Can you see if this helps you https://github.com/SaulGoodman-jl/spring-6-restclient/blob/39ac88513d348231e28e81a9480486b6d9b3a959/src/test/java/guru/springframework/spring6restclient/client/BeerClientMockTest.java#L84

Did definitely find some inspiration in there, thanks! With a bit of tweaking to get it to fit for my use case with Wiremock, Azure AD, I now solved it
